# Objective-C: Child-parent type circular references, leaking?

Tags: objective-c, circular-reference

How does one avoid memory leaks in a relationship like this?

```
@class Node;

@interface Node : NSObject {
  Node *parent;
  Node *child;
  id object;
}

-(id)initWithObject:(id)anObject;
-(id)object;
-(void)setChild:(Node *)aNode;
-(void)setParent:(Node *)aNode;

@end


@implementation Node

-(id)initWithObject:(id)anObject {
  if (self = [self init]) {
    object = [anObject retain];
  }
  return self;
}

-(id)object {
  return object;
}

-(void)setParent:(Node *)aNode {
  [parent release];
  parent = [aNode retain];
}

-(void)setChild:(Node *)aNode {
  [child release];
  child = [aNode retain];
  [child setParent:self];
}

-(void)dealloc {
  [child release];
  [parent release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

```
Node *root = [[Node alloc] initWithObject:@"foo"]; // root retain = 1
Node *child = [[Node alloc] initWithObject:@"bar"]; // child retain = 1

[root setChild:child]; // child retain = 2, root retain = 2

[root release]; // root retain = 1
[child release]; // child retain = 1

/* Leaking! */
```

If you don't know up-front `root` should be dealloc'd, you only care that you no longer need it, how and where does the reference count drop to zero?

Also, would the Leaks application even detect this as a leak?  I suspect I may have been bitten by this as I'm trying to track down what seems to be a leak, but Leaks claims I have no leaks.  Since child still references parent, and vice-versa, I dare say Leaks considers the objects to still be referenced, and therefore not leaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb it's a bad idea to retain a a hierarchical ancestor in a parent child relationship.  It causes these "retain cycles" where your objects won't get deallocated when they are suppose to.  There's an excellent explanation of the problem [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html) with nice pictures and advice.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  In short, use assignment in `-setParent:` and in the `-dealloc` method send `setParent:nil` to the child. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing.  Am I right in thinking this type of memory leak would be invisible to a leak detection tool?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, it's been a while since I've used leaks :(

Comment: No, `leaks` and/or Instruments should be able to pick up this kind of leak as long as the entire hierarchy is not reachable from the stack or static/global memory.

Comment: Interesting.  It didn't seem to detect this one.  I only had an inkling that it was related to a circular reference.  I open Activity Monitor, note memory use from my app, open a document, make some changes, close document, memory has increased. Repeat.  Memory goes up again, etc.  I just now removed the source of the leak.  A circular reference between a NSView and an NSViewController.  Memory now goes up and back down as expected when I open and close documents.  Leaks did not see this.

Answer (score 3):

Apples documentation on [retain cycles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html) also points you to how to break them: use [weak references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1044135-BCICCFAE) on one side, in this case probably for the parents.

Note that there are other problems with what you posted: 
Consider e.g. `-setChild:` when `aNode==child`. The `child` instance will be deallocated before the `-retain` if nothing else holds a (strong) reference to it.

To fix that use either:

```
if (aNode != child) {
    // ... same as before
}
```

or:

```
Node *tmp = child;
child = [aNode retain];
[tmp release];
```

Comment: Yikes, thanks, I will have repeated similar code in other places so I'll have to fix that!